# Firebase Cloud Functions Check Value is not empty

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my cloud function, I take the JSON body and particular elements of it.

```
const type = request.body.type;
```

But what if type was optional. And the user didn't have to put it. Is there a way of doing the above without it erroring out.

Because in the instant above, if the user left "type" out of their object, then it would cause an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you want to check if there is a `type` property in the `request`'s body.

The following should do the trick:

```
if (request.body.type) {
    //There is a type, act accordingly
} else {
    //No type
}
```